# QtQuick Controls for armfh kit Ubuntu SDK (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 15.04, ubuntu-sdk, qml, qt-creator

An app that I am working on compiles and runs fine on the desktop but when run from the Aquaris 4.5 Ubuntu SDK keeps throwing messages about QtQuick Controls not found. On checking the path, I found that the controls are indeed not available under the armfh directory (/var/lib/schroots/click-ubuntu-sdk-15.04-armfh/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/qml).

The app's desktop version runs without complaints but when I try to run it on the phone, it complains.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use QtQuick Controls, or ship the QtQuick Controls you need as part of your application.

Ubuntu provides its own set of QML widgets under the [Ubuntu.Components namespace](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04/Ubuntu.Components/), instead of using those provided by QtQuick Controls.  If you want your app to feel native on an Ubuntu device, you should use those widgets.

If that's undesirable or impossible, you may be able to include the controls you need from QtQuick Controls in your click package.  I don't know how easy this would be offhand.  There may be several layers of dependencies, and it's likely that some are written in C++ and will need to be compiled.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot for your response Robert. Will try

Comment: Hi Robert. The app runs without QtControls. But certain components like AnimatedImage won't work. How to incorporate these?

Comment: Ask about it in another question.